# Proxy class cannot access Method in inherited interface

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF Setup something like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface A {

  [OperationContract( Name = "Log_1" )]
  void Log( AuthTicket authTicket, string message );
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface B : A { 

  [OperationContract( Name = "Log_2" )]
  void Log( AuthTicket authTicket, LogLevel level, string message );
}
```

In my proxy class, I can call B.Log() without problems.  Intellisense sees A.Log(), but at runtime I get an exception when calling it:

> Method Log is not supported on this proxy, this can happen if the
>   method is not marked with OperationContractAttribute or if the
>   interface type is not marked with ServiceContractAttribute.

Why can't my proxy "see" the A.Log() overload?  If I move the declaration of A.Log() to interface B, it works, so it isn't simply a naming collision.

Comment: Did you try to set some [KnownType Attributes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108076/wcf-interface-return-type-and-knowntypes)?

Comment: We do have ServiceKnownType set on both interfaces.

Comment: The following article may be helpful ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg598929.aspx